# compare two drop down values

Tags: jquery

I need a function that will compare two values from two drop-down selectors and if they are the same show a div. I'd like to use jQuery, if possible.

```
<select id="drop1">
   <option value="a">a
   <option value="b">b
   <option value="c">c
</select>

<select id="drop2">
   <option value="a">a
   <option value="b">b
   <option value="c">c
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$("#myDiv").toggle($("#drop1").val() === $("#drop2").val());
```

Explanation: `$("#dropX").val()` gets the value of the selected element in that dropdown; the `===` compares them, giving `true` or `false` as appropriate; and `$("myDiv").toggle(...)` either shows or hides `#myDiv` depending on the passed value.

If you want to do this whenever the value changes, wrap this in `$("#drop1, #drop2").change(function () { ... });` as in nickf's answer.

Comment: Nice and handy overload of the toggle func., but why 3 ===?

Comment: `==` only compares the values, but coerces types if they are unequal (so e.g. `null == "" == undefined == 0`); `===` requires type equality as well (so `null === null`, but `null !== ""` and `null !== undefined` and so on). ALWAYS Using `===` is best practice.

Comment: @Eric If only there were a web site that answered questions like that-- oh wait! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$('#drop1, #drop2').change(function() {
    $('#myDiv').toggle(
        $('#drop1').val() === $('#drop2').val()
    );
});
```